# R submit to CRAN: which R version to build package?

Tags: r, package, version, cran

I want to submit a package to CRAN. In the [CRAN repository policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) 
it states that 
**"Packages for which R CMD check gives an ‘ERROR’ when a new R x.y.0 version is released will be archived"**.

It also says **"Please ensure that R CMD check --as-cran has been run on the tarball to be uploaded before submission"**.

Running `R CMD check --as cran` on my tarball gives me the warning:

```
Warning: unknown option ‘--as-cran’
```

I am running R version 2.14.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Can I build a source package using this version or do I have to use R 3.0?

And why does `R CMD check --as-cran` not work for me?

Comment: When you say `R CMD check --as-cran` doesn't work for you, what do you mean? What error message to you get?

Comment: I get no error but the warning as posted above.

Comment: Your R version doesn't have the `--as-cran` check, because it was introduced in R 2.14.2 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document you link to says:

> Please ensure that R CMD check --as-cran has been run on the tarball
>   to be uploaded before submission. This should be done with the current
>   release of R or (preferably) R-devel or R-patched.

So, right now, you should use **R-3.0.1** and also test against the R-devel branch (if possible).

Comment: This sounds reasonable, I am trying to install R 3.0.1 now to see if `R CMD check --as-cran` works.

Comment: Just installed R 3 and it does not give the warning for the `--as-cran` argument anymore. I will check my package with this version before submitting. Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to add the argument `--vanilla` too, though maybe this is captured in `--as-cran`.  It ensures that none of your local files are read during start up.

Comment: Or use `devtools::check()` which does it's best to simulate exactly what cran does.

Answer (score 1):

From the current October 2015 CRAN policy:
"Please ensure that R CMD check --as-cran has been run on the tarball to be uploaded before submission. This should be done with the current version of **R-devel** (or if that is not possible and explained in the submission, current R-patched or the current release of R.)"

This, I believe is a change from the policy described in the original accepted answer.

`docker`/`rocker` is a way to achieve this fairly easily without mucking up your development environment.

I think it is correct to build with the latest release version, but test with R-devel and the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new `starfox/r-devel` container available at https://hub.docker.com/r/starfox/r-devel/. It contains already some packages, which will make your release more convenient. There is also a [guide how to use it](http://dsnor.blogspot.de/2015/10/how-to-check-and-release-your-r-package.html).

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of both, the container and the guide.